# Replacing string with its length after a symbol

Tags: java

Let's take this string as example:

```
Select * from tbl_users where age>@age and name=@name or lastname=@lastname order by @thing
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to replace a string with its length after @ symbol. And after that removing that symbol.

So the output would look like this:

```
Select * from tbl_users where age>3 and name=4 or lastname=8 order by 5
```

So far I have tried doing that with regex., so it's universal method for any similar string. But can't totally make it to work...

Any help with that would be appreciated.

**Edit: it has nothing to do with sql / databases.
This string is just example for complexity**

Comment: I'm just taking a step back from your problem, and I'm finding myself asking why you think you want to do this.  Unless your database actually has people named `4` or `Ms. 8` in it...

Comment: No it's Java and nothing to do with databases. This string is just example.

Comment: Are you trying to make these values configurable in java?

Comment: Can you show your Java code?

Comment: No, I just want input that string or similar in method, remove @, and replace following words with its length and print out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for this. The following regex will group any string starting with the `@` symbol up to the first white space or the end of the string.

```
(@.*?)(?:\s|$)
```

After that, it is just a matter of looping over the groups and replacing the found groups with its own length - 1 (because the `@` symbol is part of the group).

```
private static final String regex = "(@.*?)(?:\\s|$)";
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

private static String replaceAnnotationsWithLength(String string) {
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

  while (matcher.find()) {
    string = string.replace(matcher.group(1), Integer.toString(matcher.group(1).length() - 1));
  }

  return string;
}
```

Now calling

```
replaceAnnotationsWithLength(
    "Select * from tbl_users where age>@age and name=@name or lastname=@lastname order by @thing")
```

will return

```
Select * from tbl_users where age>3 and name=4 or lastname=8 order by 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Pattern class like this,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Your Code here
        String s = "Select * from tbl_users where age>@age and name=@name or lastname=@lastname order by @thing";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@(\\S*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        StringBuffer bufStr = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()){
            Integer i =  m.group(1).length();
            m.appendReplacement(bufStr,i.toString());
        }

        String s1 = bufStr.toString();
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Regex: `@(\\S*)` will match all non-whitespace characters starting with @ symbol. The output of the above code is,

```
Select * from tbl_users where age>3 and name=4 or lastname=8 order by 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
public static String getReplace(String str, String symbol) {
    String newString = str;
    while (newString.contains(symbol)) {
        int index = newString.indexOf(symbol);
        int nextSpace = newString.indexOf(" ", index);
        if (nextSpace == -1)
            nextSpace = newString.length();
        newString = newString.substring(0, index) + (nextSpace - index - 1) + newString.substring(nextSpace);
    }
    return newString;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Select * from tbl_users where age>@age and name=@name or lastname=@lastname order by @thing";
    String symbol = "@";
    str = getReplace(str, symbol);
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

will print

```
Select * from tbl_users where age>3 and name=4 or lastname=8 order by 5
```